# Java Runtime Error InputMismatchException in program

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error, inputmismatchexception

When I run this code I get this code in coderunner (an app that submits code for schoolwork)

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double maxn = -90;
    double maxs = 90;
    double maxe = 180;
    double maxw = -180;
    double lat = 0;
    double longa = 0;
    int x = 1;

    while (x != 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a latitude:");
        lat = scan.nextDouble();
        if (lat >= maxn && lat <= 90)
            maxn = lat;
        if (lat <= maxs && lat >= -90)
            maxs = lat;

        System.out.println("Please enter a longitude:");
        longa = scan.nextDouble();
        if (longa <= maxe && longa >= -180)
            maxe = longa;
        if (longa >= maxw && longa <= 180)
            maxw = longa;

        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another location?");
        x = scan.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Farthest North: " + maxn + "\nFarthest South: " + maxs + "\nFarthest East: " + maxe + "\nFarthest West: " + maxw);
```

I get the following error:

```
    Runtime Error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Lesson_20_Activity.main(Main.java:315)
at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:85)
at Ideone.assertRegex(Main.java:76)
at Ideone.test(Main.java:40)
at Ideone.main(Main.java:29)
```

I have no idea how this error works, as I am new to coding. Can someone explain what this means and how to fix it?

EDIT: My input is

`Please enter the latitude:
41.678
Please enter the longitude:
69.938
Would you like to enter another location?
1
Please enter the latitude:
41.755
Please enter the longitude:
69.862
Would you like to enter another location?
1
Please enter the latitude:
41.829
Please enter the longitude:
69.947
Would you like to enter another location?
1
Please enter the latitude:
300
Please enter the longitude:
69.947
Incorrect Latitude or Longitude
Please enter the latitude:
41.827
Please enter the longitude: 
69.904
Would you like to enter another location?
0
Farthest North: 41.829
Farthest South: 41.678
Farthest East: 69.947
Farthest West: 69.862`

Also, I have tried changing x to a double and a string input, with no success. The error I got for each is NoSuchElementError and NoSuchLineError (respectively)

Comment: what's the input you gave?

Comment: This is my input

Answer (score 1):

From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), `InputMismatchException` is thrown when:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

In your code, you are calling `scan.nextInt()` and `scan.nextDouble()`. Make sure that you are only passing valid `int` and `double` values respectively to each of these calls. That is, inputting a double value when the Scanner is expecting an int value (`scan.nextInt()`) would throw the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you don't want a line break you should them use the System.out.print then write '\r\n'.

I have run your code and got the right output, but you have to notice what input are you giving to your command line. I'd read all Strings and then convert to the desired primitive format to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

After you enter longitude and latitude, you are asking for the question where you try again.

```
x= nextInt()
```

Here, You are accepting an int (0 to close the while loop, not otherwise). 
If you type any string or double value there, it will cause Inputmismtach exception. I tried your code, and it works fine if those integers and decimals are given correcly as shown below.

```
Please enter a latitude:
12.3
Please enter a longitude:
14.3
Would you like to enter another location?
1
Please enter a latitude:
12.3
Please enter a longitude:
14.5
Would you like to enter another location?
0
Farthest North: 12.3
Farthest South: 12.3
Farthest East: 14.3
Farthest West: 14.5
```